# Change Ubuntu EFI location

Tags: grub2, uefi, bootloader, grub-efi

On MacBook, Ubuntu installs EFI in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`. How can I change the installation folder to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu0`?

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) is mounted at `/boot/efi`. You can change this mount point by editing its entry in `/etc/fstab`; however, doing so is inadvisable because system utilities and documented procedures may *assume* that the ESP is mounted there, and therefore malfunction if you mount the ESP elsewhere.

Note that the [Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) is firmware that's installed in chips on the computer's motherboard. The EFI *reads* files on the ESP to boot (with some caveats), but it is not *installed* to the ESP. What's installed to the ESP is boot loader(s) and related files, such as GRUB (`grubx64.efi`). Boot loaders *must* be installed to the ESP, or at least to a partition that the EFI can read; installing them elsewhere will render them useless.

A caveat: On Macs, the EFI can read boot loaders from HFS+ volumes, and Apple stores its own boot loader on an HFS+ volume. This defies the EFI standard, but only in a minor way. Third-party boot loaders, including Ubuntu's GRUB, normally go on the ESP. In theory, they could be installed to an HFS+ volume, but Ubuntu does not currently support this configuration.

So, with all that out of the way: What are you *actually* trying to accomplish? Doing what you're asking would be useless at best, so I suspect you want to accomplish something you're not saying.

Answer (score 1):

On modern computers all boot loaders are getting (and have to be) installed to the EFI partition. The `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` folder is the default installation location for the GRUB boot loader. When you try to install the boot loader to another location, the operating system does not start.